# Trying to add elseif statement in excel-vba will not paste or copy

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add elseif statement but in excel it does not copy and paste from sheet 3 or sheet4 what did i do wrong about this code?

```
Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:I500").ClearContents
For i = 2 To LastRow

If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Hong Kong" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "United Kingdom" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "New zealand" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Australia" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I assume "it does not copy and paste from sheet 3 or sheet4" is meant to say "to" and not "from".  Correct?

Comment: what it does see which country from sheet 1 and copy and paste  from either sheet 3 if  UK or sheet 4 NZ but it does not paste or copy at all

Comment: Your condition is never correct, if you define a (string) value as upper case  `UCase`and compare it with a string that includes lower case

Comment: UCase("hong kong") will be "HONG KONG", it won't be "Hong Kong".

Comment: How do i do it since my just practicing vba excel im new this coding.

Comment: Change what you are checking against to be upper case, e.g. `If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "HONG KONG" Then` or `If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("Hong Kong") Then`

Comment: But I am still worried that your comment says you want to copy **FROM** sheet 3 and sheet 4, because your code is trying to copy **TO** those sheets.

Comment: no sheet 1 has the data wanted to transfer each country to their specific sheets but none of them are copy and paste in specific sheets2 to sheet5

Comment: OK, so it is just that you need to make both sides of the `=` be in upper-case

Comment: no it just don't transfer from sheet3  United Kingdom if my sheet 1 has untied Kingdom when i look at sheet3 it has all blanks

Comment: That is because `"UNITED KINGDOM" = "United Kingdom"` returns `False`.  You will need to make both sides of the `=` to be in upper-case if you want it to possibly return `True`.  (And please stop saying "transfer FROM sheet3" if you mean "transfer TO sheet3".  You will confuse us.)

Comment: problem is the code is running my data from sheet 1 has all data but when i try to insert from sheet 3, sheet4, sheet 5 it all blank no data has been inserted. Can only insert from sheet2.

Comment: Your code is writing TO (not FROM) sheets 2, 3, 4 and 5.  And it sounds like you want it to write TO those sheets if they are currently blank. (It wouldn't make sense copying FROM blank sheets.) But your code will only copy TO those sheets once you fix your `If` statements.

Comment: How can i fix my if statement just new to this vba excel code.

Comment: See my earlier comment, i.e. "Change what you are checking against to be upper case, e.g. `If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "HONG KONG" Then` or `If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("Hong Kong") Then`", and my answer.

Comment: the elseif statement problem sheet 1 can't insert from sheet3

Comment: Why are trying to insert FROM sheet3?  Aren't you trying to write something TO sheet3?  If you are trying to insert something TO sheet3, just fix your `If` statements.  Sigh - I'm calling it a night.

Comment: Nevermind i got it

Answer (score 1):

Your `If` statements, such as `If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Hong Kong" Then` are comparing something that has been converted to upper case with something that is definitely NOT upper case, so will never be `True`.

For instance, if cell B5 contained "hong kong", when you do `UCase` of that you get "HONG KONG".  A comparison of `"HONG KONG" = "Hong Kong"` will equate to `False`.

You should use statements such as

```
If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "HONG KONG" Then
```

or, if you are lazy and don't want to press the Caps Lock key while typing, you could use

```
If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("Hong Kong") Then
```

Either of those two will ensure that both sides of the comparison are in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer provided by YowE3K, you didn't declare your variables, please see below:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'above declare variables

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Sheet1 Column A

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:I500").ClearContents
'clear Sheet2's given range

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
    If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = "HONG KONG" Then 
   'you can either compare against HONG KONG or like below UCase("Hong Kong")
        ws.Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("United Kingdom") Then
        ws.Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("New zealand") Then
        ws.Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ElseIf UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase("Australia") Then
        ws.Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```